# Are "irresistibly" and "overwhelmingly" interchangeable?

Tags: word-choice

> Computer games are extremely attractive to teenagers so they play them irresistibly day and night.

Are the two words "irresistibly" and "overwhelmingly" interchangeable in this sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, *neither* word is correct. Clearly the sense intended is that teenagers are *unable to resist* playing computer games day and night, or they are *overwhelmed by the urge* to play.

Adverbial *irresistibly* means *in an irresistible manner*. For example:

> *He seduced me irresistibly.*
>   means *He seduced me in a way I was unable to resist*,
>   it does ***not*** mean *He was unable to resist seducing me*.

By the same token, adverbial *overwhelmingly* could in principle be used to mean *in an overwhelming manner*, but that wouldn't fit OP's context for the same reason as above. In practice *overwhelmingly* is rarely used with that sense; it's almost exclusively restricted to the metaphoric figurative usage where it means *by far the greater part*, oir *almost all*. Thus:

> *My superiors in this company are overwhelmingly male.*
>   means *My superiors are almost all men*,
>   it certainly doesn't mean they're *overwhelmed by "the urge to be men"* (whatever that would mean!),
>   nor does it mean *My superiors treat me in an overwhelming manner*.

---

The normal way to express what OP wants to say is:

> *Computer games are extremely attractive to teenagers, so they play them **compulsively** day & night.*

You do something *compulsively* when you're *compelled* to; you *can't resist* or you're *overwhelmed by* the urge to do it. But note it's only used of things you're compelled to do by *your own inner motivations* - normally only in contexts where those motivations are excessive or abnormal in some way. For example:

> She cleans my house compulsively.
>   does ***not*** mean she is compelled by me (or anyone else) to do the cleaning,
>   it means she has an [abnormal] uncontrollable urge to clean my house [thoroughly and frequently].

Comment: +1 Yep, "compulsively" seems a much better word here.

Answer (score 2):

No, they're not interchangeable in your sentence. *Irresistibly* means that they cannot prevent themselves from playing the games day and night, but *overwhelmingly* means *extremely*, which cannot meaningfully replace *irresistibly* in this sentence.

Consider: *PC gamers are **overwhelmingly** male* and *PC gamers are **irresistibly** male*. The first sentence is meaningful: >70% of PC gamers are male. The second sentence is nonsense.

If you replace *irresistibly* with *overwhelmingly* in your sentence, the sentence becomes nonsense.

Comment: Bill, I don't think that "irresistibly" is used correctly in OP.  Unless you are describing the effect an action has on others (turning them on or attracting them in some other way), you can't DO something irresistibly, can you? "Computer games are irresistible" is fine, but the adverb form (adverb of manner) modifying an action verb does not make sense to me.  You can BE irresistibly something, of course; "She was irresistibly beautiful."  Do you agree, or have I missed something? Curious to hear what you and others have to say about this.

Comment: By the way, did I use "OP" correctly?  Does it mean Original Post or Original Poster, or can it mean both?

Comment: @ShawnMooney _OP_ can mean _Original Poster_, or _Original Post_.

Comment: @ShawnMooney: Perhaps you're right about that. Perhaps the word should be "unresistingly" ("without resistance"). There seems to be a [similar usage by Robert Frost](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/15633-love-is-an-irresistible-desire-to-be-irresistibly-desired), however: "Love is an irresistible desire to be irresistibly desired." And the word has [myriad appropriate synonyms](http://thesaurus.com/browse/irresistibly?s=t). But I wouldn't object to a rewrite. Thank you for pointing this out. :-)

Comment: @kiamlaluno, sorry for this basic newbie question, but how did you italicize those words in your comment? I can easily see how to do it in an ANSWER, but have yet to figure out how to do it in a COMMENT.

Comment: @ShawnMooney: Put an underscore in front of and behind the word or phrase or sentence you want to italicize: no space between the underscore and the first letter or the underscore and the last letter. Eg, _italics_ **=** (_ [no space] italics [no space] _). I can't do it without spaces to show you or the italics will appear without the underscores.

Comment: @BillFranke, thanks.  I scanned the list of synonyms, but didn't see any that could more appropriately replace 'irresistibly' in the OP.  Did you?  Based on your fantastic Frost quote, I would expand upon my previous comment to include both adjectives and (certain?) passive verbs as exceptions.  I am curious if you agree ('certain' or 'all'?).  Perhaps there is more to it?  I am very curious and maybe I won't be able to sleep tonight until one of us nails it.  If you care about the quality of my sleep--and why should you, really?--I am counting on the next instalment of your erudition. :)

Comment: @ShawnMooney: I was thinking of "impetuously" and "passionately" in particular, but "forcefully, frantically, frenziedly, furiously" all work for me. Got to finish editing a paper now, so maybe tomorrow I can think more about this.

Comment: @BillFranke, thanks.  With the exception of _forcefully_, I agree with you, although most of the others have slightly-different nuances; however, they definitely do cut the mustard. Good luck with the paper!

Comment: @BillFranke, two more quick comments: (1) thanks for the lesson on how to _italicize_ comments, and (2) I forgot to comment on your suggested synonym for _irresistibly_, _unresistingly_; I don't think they are precisely synonymous. _Irresistibly_ describes an action or state that is INCAPABLE of being resisted, whereas _unresistingly_ describes an action/state that IS/WAS NOT resisted.  Is there not an important, non-interchangeable difference between _She unresistingly agreed to kiss me_, on the one hand, and _She kissed me irresistibly_ on the other. Your thoughts? Interesting!

Comment: Also, _unresistingly_ is extemely uncommon, I think.

Comment: Oops, of course I meant _extremely_.  Time to go to bed.